# How to async await in promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

i wnna make an API thing that load list of pokemons and when it's image.
got the list and wanna make sure the sequence on pictures will be correct for this i console.log the same names. and sequence is wrong. tried some async await in diff places and can't figure out how to get proper order
https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX

```
Promise.all(arrForFetch)
    .then(files => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log("files", file)
            process(file.json())
        })
            .catch(err => console.log("tobie pizda ucziekaj"))
    })
let process = (prom) => {
    console.log(prom)
    prom.then(data => {
        console.log(data.name)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const results = await Promise.all(arrForFetch)
// do something with results array
```

Your issue is that `file.json()` is async so needs to be returned from the loop as another Promise all, or awaited in the loop.  You can map the promises.

```
Promise.all(arrForFetch)
                 .then( files  =>{
                     const more = files.map(file=>file.json().then(process))
                     return Promise.all(more)
                   })
                  .catch(err  =>  console.log("tobie pizda ucziekaj"))
```

```
Promise.all(arrForFetch)
                 .then( async files  =>{
                     for(const i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                     console.log("files", files[i])
                     process(  await files[i].json() )
                     }
                   })
                  .catch(err  =>  console.log("tobie pizda ucziekaj"))
```

Comment: thank you.where should i write async in order to make ``` await Promise.all(arrForFetch) ``` work. like this  falls into error after first promise https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX

Comment: you dont need to await it. but if it is top level, put it in iife function. i will update answer.

Comment: i might be too st**id for coding / programming but i can't make it to work( [link]https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX